# Inconsistency in python system attribute "__file__" on different linux distros

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, dirname

I am dealing with weird problem. Consider this simple code:

```
print(__file__)
print("***" + os.path.dirname(__file__) + "###")
```

now when I run this code on my laptop, where I have Fedora 23 OS, the output is:

```
/home/.../ExperimentalSystem/BullshitSetupGenerator.py
***/home/.../ExperimentalSystem###
```

running the same code on Ubuntu 15.10:

```
BullshitSetupGenerator_delete_me.py
***###
```

can anybody explain me why? Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no inconsistency in the dirname function.  The inconsistency is in `__file__`

Comment: Is the inconsistency with `dirname` or with `__file__`?  My guess would be the latter.  Are you running the code with the same relative path in both places?  And finally, to get consistent behavior, I suppose you could use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

Comment: it's with __file__, true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to purely rely on the `__file__` attribute, but you ensure you have a full path `abspath`:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 3):

`__file__` is defined by the argument given to Python that tells it what your file is.  For example, let's say you are in a folder called `Here`.  You could say `python ../Here/here.py`, and `__file__` would be `../Here/here.py`.  If you ran the same file with just `python here.py`, `__file__` is `here.py`.  When you run the Python file in the same directory without using either an absolute path or a weird relative path, the file will not have any directories mentioned.  That means that `os.dirname(__file__)` will be blank.  If you want, you can get the absolute path with [`os.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath).